# How do you get the Announcer Badge?

Tags: support, badges

The Announcer badge says:

```
Shared a link to a question that was visited by 50 unique IP addresses in 2 days
```

But how do they know who posted the link?  If I post a Superuser link to reddit.com how do they know that it was me who posted it and that I should get the credit?  There isn't really a referral system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you're logged in you'll see that the actual link for questions is a shortened version.

On this question, it looks like this:

```
http://meta.superuser.com/q/1486/307
```

Grab and post that link to other sites and when you hit the necessary levels of referrals, you'll get your badges. The referral ID is your UserId.

You don't have to be logged in to get that link. Just know your user ID (it's the first number on your profile URI) and swap out the question ID.

Basic format of the link you'll want to share if you want that Announcer/Booster/Publicist badge.

```
http://superuser.com/q/[QuestionId]/[UserId]
```

Here's another example:

```
http://superuser.com/q/2/5003
```

#### Sidenote:

- You can't get Booster until you've already gotten Announcer.
- You can't get Publicist unless you've already gotten Booster.
- You can't get these badges for the same question.
- Only applies to questions, doesn't work for answers.
- Does not come with fur coat, cane or fedora.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Announcer badge is not applicable to Super User.</s>

Apparently, it is applicable, just hidden :P

Comment: Then why is it listed under badges? And where is it applicable?

Comment: It's applicable to the new stackexchange sites which are currently in Beta ( example: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ ). As for why it's listed - the codebase is the same - but Super User (currently) does not have the `share question` links on the questions.