# How are the referrals tracked for the Announcer badge?

Tags: support, badges, hyperlinks

I'm looking down the badges list and see the Announcer badge:
[image: Announcer Badge Description]
And so what I was wondering was how tracking/obtaining this badge is possible. Is there some kind of referral link somewhere that I don't know or does SE employ unicorns?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you get the Announcer Badge?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1486/how-do-you-get-the-announcer-badge)

Answer (score 5):

First make sure you are logged in, and then give out the `link` URL for the question, new users that come in via this URL will be counted towards your badge.

[image: Screenshot of link location; under the question's tags]

### How it works

The link on this question shows as (to *me*):
`http://meta.superuser.com/q/1758/39366`

Notice that `39366` is **my user ID** (as per the URL when looking at my user profile), which is all there is to it - unique URLs that are attributed to a specific user ID.

For more info, check out the [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/).

Comment: I love how recursive it is that you used screenshotted the question in your answer :P

Comment: How about I screenshot the question *and the answer I've written* in my next answer? :)